# Was Cassandra CAS / Lightweight transaction fixed or not

Tags: cassandra, distributed-computing

Reading Aphyr's blogpost: https://aphyr.com/posts/294-call-me-maybe-cassandra/

**No. Cassandra lightweight transactions are not even close to correct.**

Soo... is it still a problem in the recent versions or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This article is very old, and most (if not all) things found were fixed. DataStax did a lot of work around additional testing with Jepsen - there is a [blog post](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/testing-apache-cassandra-with-jepsen) and [presentation](https://www.slideshare.net/planetcassandra/datastax-testing-cassandra-guarantees-under-diverse-failure-modes-with-jepsen) about this.

Here is quote from one of the Cassandra developers in [discussion on HN](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=13592269):

> Cassandra had a minor bug with timestamps which was fixed relatively fast and now it passes Jepsen fully. There were also a few implementation issues around LWT (Paxos) but at that time Paxos was very new. There were no architectural / fundamental changes needed to correct these issues.